# Custom wordpress function not showing the right number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress function that shows the number of featured recipes. The function works fine when `showposts=-1` is in the query. However when I put 'showposts=5' only two of my posts are shown.

Below is my function

```
 function pika_featured_recipes_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); 
    echo '<div class="featured-box-heading"> Featured Recipes </div>';
    echo '<div class="featured-box">';

    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('showposts=5&post_type=cp_recipe&order=Desc&orderby=date' . '&paged=' . $paged);


    while ($wp_query->have_posts()):
    $wp_query->the_post();
    $entry_id = get_the_ID();
    $entry_link = get_permalink($entry_id);
    $entry_image = get_post_thumbnail_id($entry_id);
    $entry_title = get_the_title($entry_id);
    $entry_description = get_post_meta($entry_id, '_cp_recipe_short_description', true);
    $entry_excerpt = get_post_meta($entry_id, '_cp_recipe_excerpt', true);

    $likes = get_post_meta( $entry_id, '_cp_likes', true );

    if (get_field('featured-pika-recipe') == 'Yes') {


        echo '<div class="featured-result-box item ">
        <div class="box">
        <div class="pika-featured-box-img">';
        if(!empty($entry_image)) {
            echo '<a href="'.$entry_link.'">'.wp_get_attachment_image($entry_image, 'cp_298_192').'</a>';
        } 
        echo' </div><!-- /.box-img -->';

        echo'<div class="box-entry">
        <h5 class="pika-featured-title"><a href="'; 
        echo $entry_link;
        echo '">';
        echo $entry_title; 
        echo'</a></h5>';
        echo $trimmed = wp_trim_words( $entry_description, $num_words = 15, $more = null );

        echo'</div><!-- /.box-entry -->';
        echo'</div>';
        echo'</div>';

        echo'<div style="clear:both"></div>';
    }

    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
    echo '</div>';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;}



add_shortcode( 'pika_featured-recipes', 'pika_featured_recipes_shortcode' );
```

The problem seems to be  with

```
if (get_field('featured-pika-recipe') == 'Yes') {
```

removing this and the number of posts appear fine. Any way i can resolve this?

Comment: On this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query I see that posts_per_age has replaced showposts parameter starting with wp v2.1 , so was just curious what version of WP you are on

Comment: @Satya im on version 4.2

Comment: @Satya, `showposts` [still works](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2463)

Comment: Yeah, there wouldn't be. I re-checked the source, and noticed that WP converts the case internally.

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be with  'if (get_field('featured-pika-recipe') == 'Yes') {' removing this and the number of posts appear fine

Comment: Your shortcode is a mess. You have a crap load of undefined variables in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe because only 2 posts ( of the last 5 posts that you actually call ) got

`get_field('featured-pika-recipe') == 'Yes'`

you can try to add this custom field directly to your query to get last 5 posts with this custom field with following code

```
'meta_key'      => 'featured-pika-recipe',
'meta_value'    => 'Yes'
```

Comment: the following page can help you to add custom fields to wordpress query http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/